# Selecting a element by ID dynamically (JS/jQuery)

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery

I have a list of html elements which I want to target one at a time such as:

`thisIsAnId1`

`thisIsAnId2`

`thisIsAnId3`

I would like to select these individually and dynamically with jQuery, however due to the way jQuery works on apex components, I'm a little bit stuck.

In the following answers it seems simple:

[jquery dynamic id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895528/jquery-dynamic-id)

[jQuery selection with dynamic id's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408265/jquery-selection-with-dynamic-ids)

However due to Visualforce elements requiring selection with `$("[id$=thisIsAnId1]")` I can't seem to get it to work.

This is what I'm trying at the moment:

`j$("[id$=categoryDelivery]" + deliveryRowsAdded).text`

Is there any way to do this?

**Clearup Edit**

HOW DO I DO THIS?

```
var deliveryRowsAdded = 0;
j$("[id$=categoryDelivery]" + deliveryRowsAdded).text
```

Comment: Do you have these as visualforce components or simple html components?? I see you said html elements but i want to reconfirm it.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Yes, `<select>` and `<input>` elements to be precise

Comment: Then there is no need to worry. JQuery will work fine.Probably it's time for you to paste your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel below syntax will work:

`$("[id*=thisIsAnId]")`

This basically means select elements where id contains 'thisIsAnId'.

Here is some sample implementation:

```
<input type="text" value="1" id="thisIsAnId1" />
 <input type="text" value="2" id="thisIsAnId2" />
 <input type="text" value="3" id="thisIsAnId3" />
 <Script>
 $("[id*=thisIsAnId]").each(function() {
 this.style.color = "blue";
 });
 </Script>
```

Here is another solution based on variable index as per your requirement:

```
 <input type="text" value="1" id="thisIsAnId1" />
 <input type="text" value="2" id="thisIsAnId2" />
 <input type="text" value="3" id="thisIsAnId3" />
 <Script>
 for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) { 


    alert($("[id*='thisIsAnId" + i+ "']"));

}
 </script>
```

Comment: How can I target them independently one at a time? Thanks.

Comment: @SamCousins See improved answer.

Comment: Thanks Mukesh, but I need it to be able to take into account the value of "deliveryRowsAdded", which is an integer. I can't reference them later with `.each()`

Comment: @SamCousins If you'd add some sample code to your post of your visualforce, you'd be able to get a much more specific answer and not waste everyone't time.

Comment: @crmprogdev I have edited my original post. I don't see how it's wasting time, I have explained my requirements as clearly as I can AND included exactly what I'm trying to achieve. If you have any constructive criticism on how I can improve the question and narrow it down, feel free.

Comment: @SamCousins : Posted another example with a variable index and id created at runtime. Hope that helps.

Comment: @SamCousins In pageblocktables, regular html tables, or other related markup, Id's can be obtained by various methods which don't at all apply to your question, that is, unless you plan to nest your inputs inside a pagetableblock or other formatting. Thus, the benefit of knowing the type of mark-up your were using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to select all elements starting with "thisIsAnId", then you can use this :

`$("[name^='thisIsAnId']").text`

Comment: Thanks SF Ninja, I'm trying to select them one at a time unfortunately. I need to be able to pull the values from each individual one, but deliveryRowsAdded could be any number.